# Mail not sending when submitting form

Tags: php, forms, email

For some reason this form is not working and not sending out emails through submitting the form. It says the form has successfully submitted but it never sends anything. What is causing the problem? Please help.

```
    <?php
$id = protect($_GET['id']);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id='$id'");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)==0) { header("Location: $web[url]"); }
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
?>
<section class="dashboard content">
    <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="span12">
                    <h3>Contact with Owner</h3>
                    <?php
                    if(isset($_POST['do_send'])) {
                        $item_name = protect($_POST['item_name']);
                        $name = protect($_POST['name']);
                        $email = protect($_POST['email']);
                        $subject = protect($_POST['subject']);
                        $message = protect($_POST['message']);

                        if(empty($name) or empty($email) or empty($subject) or empty($message)) { echo error("All fields are required."); }
                        elseif(!isValidEmail($email)) { echo error("Please enter a valid email address."); }
                        else {
                                $get = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admins ORDER BY id LIMIT 1"));
                                $admin_email = $get['email'];
                                $to = $admin_email;
                                $headers  = "From: $email\r\n"; 
                                $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n"; 
                                $subjectt = $web[sitename].' - Message from '.$name;
                                $messaget = '<html><body><table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2"><tr><td><span style="font-size:30px;font-weight:bold;">'.$web[sitename].'</span><br></td></tr><tr><td>You have new message from user for item. Here is message details:</td></tr><tr><td>From: '.$name.' ('.$email.')</td></tr><tr><td>Item: '.$row[name].'</td></tr><tr><td>Subject: '.$subject.'</td></tr><tr><td>Message:<br/>'.nl2br($message).'</td></tr></table></body></html>';
                                mail($to, $subjectt, $messaget, $headers);
                                echo success("Your message was sent successfully.");
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                    <form action="" method="POST">
                            <div class="bg-color white rounded-top">
                                <div class="box-padding">
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                      <label class="control-label" for="inputUsername">Item</label>
                                      <div class="controls">
                                        <input type="text" id="inputUsername" name="item_name" class="input-block-level" disabled value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>">
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                      <label class="control-label" for="inputUsername">Your name</label>
                                      <div class="controls">
                                        <input type="text" id="inputUsername" name="name" class="input-block-level">
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                      <label class="control-label" for="inputUsername">Your email address</label>
                                      <div class="controls">
                                        <input type="text" id="inputUsername" name="email" class="input-block-level">
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                      <label class="control-label" for="inputUsername">Subject</label>
                                      <div class="controls">
                                        <input type="text" id="inputUsername" name="subject" class="input-block-level">
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                      <label class="control-label" for="inputUsername">Message</label>
                                      <div class="controls">
                                        <textarea name="message" class="input-block-level" rows="4"></textarea>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="bg-color dark-blue rounded-bottom">
                                <div class="box-padding narrow-horizontal">
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                      <div class="controls">
                                        <button type="submit" name="do_send" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                </div>

            </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

The contact form is here: http://rocketraiser.com/contact/13546224#sthash.HnYyaGGz.0o0gQ4nS.dpbs

The contact form brings in the individual item name.

Please can you show me how to fix this. Thank you very much.

-Harry

Answer (score 0):

Could be that the form has no action, by the looks of that code, the action should be the same URL the form is in

Comment: So would the action be '/' or '/contact'?

Comment: I like to use absolute URLs, but that's just me, so it could be either http://rocketraiser.com/contact or just /contact